# Why does the Unruh effect not cause a physical contradiction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, unruh-effect

If the Unruh effect says that the temperature of space depends on one's acceleration, such that an accelerating observer will observe that hir vacuum consists of a thermal bath at some elevated temperature, then how come this does not lead to hir observing objectively different temperature-related phenomena in hir frame than an observer at rest? What I mean by that is this: suppose that in the space there is an ice cube, and the observers are sitting next to or passing by it. The observer at rest will see the cube as frozen. But suppose the accelerating observer is accelerating so hard that to hir, sie sees the space as having a temperature above the freezing point of water. Why then will sie not observe the ice cube to be melting? (Two observers cannot disagree on whether or not an object is melted, after all. Also, if you think something like "sie is moving too fast to perceive it" then just make the 'ice cube' really REALLY small, like a tiny cluster of molecules kind of small, and also at a suitably large distance.)

Comment: May be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5892

Comment: Why do you expect different observers to agree on the temperature? Remember that only inertial observables are physically indistinguishable. Accelerated observers are different, and there could be different experimental setups which are designed to distinguish between them. The one with Unruh effect is just one of many. (I was tempted to post this as an answer, but since you won't probably agree, decided to leave it as a comment for now.)

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I think the OP agrees that they will *not* agree on the temperature, but thinks that they *must* agree on whether an ice cube has melted.

Comment: @innisfree Well the physics of phase transitions depends on the temperature in the rest frame of the cube, not on how some accelerating observer perceives it.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus : If the surrounding space is at an elevated temperature, would not the observer see this heat transferring to the object in question and thus melting it? If not, how in hir accelerated frame does sie account for the fact that the heat of the space is _not_ transferring to the object? I suppose this could be considered even more simply than thinking about melting - why does sie not observe the object to increase in temperature, absorbing heat from the surrounding heat bath? Or does sie actually observe the _object_ to have elevated temperature, too (in which (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) case why would if sie can accelerate hard enough that the temperature would be elevated above the freezing point, sie would not also see it as melted? How does sie account for the high temperature and yet retention of its structural integrity?)? That is, how does sie give account of the failure of heat to transfer from one to the other despite thermodynamics saying that because the two reservoirs are in contact, there should be a heat transfer?